# 4G Reverse SSH tunnel through a port forwarded VPN?

Tags: ssh, vpn, port-forwarding, reverse-tunnel

So I have a laptop connected to the 4G network the only problem is I want to connect to it via SSH from my PC.
So far I have discovered that ny network operator does not allow port forwarding but I can connect to a VPN that does.

So far I have set my tun0 (4G) device as default and have tried to reverse tunnel into it using the -R specifiers using SSH but with no luck. The whole route would look like this.

MyPc->MyRouter->Internet->VPN(Port forwarded)->4G Network->MyLaptop

I have tried:

```
ssh -R VPNPortforwardPort:localhost:LocalBindingPort "MyPcUserName"@MyPcIP
ssh -R 20257:localhost:22 "Dirk Dirksen"@my.ip.add.res
```

But I get a timeout. I have also enabled my sshd_config to allow 'GatewayPorts yes' and still no luck. 
I have also set my home router to port forward 5555 to 22 to MyPc.

When I enable my VPN and then request port forwarding I get a number like 20257 which in the localhost I try to bind to port 22 but still no luck, I just get a time out response.

So what im getting a bit confused about is the port numbers and all this port forwarding. My home router is making 22->5555 and then my VPN to the laptop gives me 20257 and then I need to connect to port 22 through that 20257 and iptables has everything set to allow.

I'm not sure if this is even possible. It must be. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The answer might not be relevant for your specific use case. But, if your problem is having access to a machine which is not physically accessible to you then read on.

I had a (potentially) similar problem a couple of weeks back trying to hook up one of our work machines for the quarantine where we had a similar block for port forwarding and did not manage to solve it.

What solved it for us was to leave a copy of team viewer open on the PC, set an option to never turn it off, and from there it was pretty straight forward.

Comment: Another sweet solution might be parsec, I was just watching this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B821HqH-dWI) and it could be better than team viewer.